# Does class_getInstanceSize have a known bug about returning incorrect sizes?

Tags: objective-c

Reading through the other questions that are similar to mine, I see that most people want to know why you would need to know the size of an instance, so I'll go ahead and tell you although it's not really central to the problem. I'm working on a project that requires allocating thousands to hundreds of thousands of very small objects, and the default allocation pattern for objects simply doesn't cut it. I've already worked around this issue by creating an object pool class, that allows a tremendous amount of objects to be allocated and initialized all at once; deallocation works flawlessly as well (objects are returned to the pool).

It actually works perfectly and isn't my issue, but I noticed `class_getInstanceSize` was returning unusually large sizes. For instance, a class that stores one `size_t` and two (including `isA`) `Class` instance variables is reported to be 40-52 bytes in size. I give a range because calling `class_getInstanceSize` multiple times, even in a row, has no guarantee of returning the same size. In fact, every object but `NSObject` seemingly reports random sizes that are far from what they should be.

As a test, I tried:

```
printf("Instance Size: %zu\n", class_getInstanceSize(objc_getClass("MyClassName"));
```

That line of code always returns a value that corresponds to the size that I've calculated by hand to be correct. For instance, the earlier example comes out to 12 bytes (32-bit) and 24 bytes (64-bit).

Thinking that the runtime may be doing something behind the scenes that requires more memory, I watched the actual memory use of each object. For the example given, the only memory read from or written to is in that 12/24 byte block that I've calculated to be the expected size.

`class_getInstanceSize` acts like this on both the Apple & GNU 2.0 runtime. So is there a known bug with `class_getInstanceSize` that causes this behavior, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong? Before you blame my object pool; I've tried this same test in a brand new project using both the traditional `alloc` class method and by allocating the object using `class_createInstance(self, 0);` in a custom class method.

Two things I forgot to mention before: I'm almost entirely testing this on my own custom classes, so I know the trickery isn't down to the class actually being a class cluster or any of that nonsense; second, `class_getInstanceSize([MyClassName class])` and `class_getInstanceSize(self) \\ Ran inside a class method` rarely produce the same result, despite both simply referencing `isA`. Again, this happens in both runtimes.

Comment: What *exactly* is the code that returns incorrect results? You've described a few different things, but haven't shown the code. If the bug is as blatant as you say -- it happens with every class other than NSObject -- then you ought to be able to distill it down to a simple test case.

Comment: @KurtRevis The exact code is - (size_t)getInstanceSize:(Class)aClass { return class_getInstanceSize(aClass); }. I've encapsulated the function in a method for testing purposes (such as printing results), but that's all there is to it. Feed it any class aside from NSObject, obtained in any way you please and you get the results described above.

Comment: @KurtRevis I should mention that I've further tested another new project (command-line only; 10.8.2 Intel Mac) that seems to act much more like you'd expect; NSObject is 8 bytes; an empty subclass is 16 bytes, and the instance size seems to increase in 16 byte chunks, most likely for memory alignment purposes. At this point I'm entirely stumped; from a default Cocoa project, I've distilled this issue down to a simple class that inherits from NSObject and the call class_getInstanceSize([MyClassName class]); and it still exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: `class_getInstanceSize()` rounds up to 16-byte boundaries. The system allocator never allocates on anything smaller than 16-byte boundaries, so that's harmless. The rounding is performed so that `class_getInstanceSize()` and `object_getIndexedIvars()` match, and so that the result of `object_getIndexedIvars()` can always be used with vector types that require 16-byte alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've solved the problem and it was due to possibly the dumbest reason ever.

I use a profiling/debugging library that is old; in fact, I don't know its actual name (the library is libcsuomm; the header for it has no identifying info). All I know about it is that it was a library available on the computers in the compsci labs (I did a year of Comp-Sci before switching to a Geology major, graduating and never looking back).

Anyway, the point of the library is that it provides a number of profiling and debugging functionalities; the one I use it most for is memory leak detection, since it actually tracks per object unlike my other favorite memory-leak library (now unsupported, MSS) which is based in C and not aware of objects outside of raw allocations.

Because I use it so much when debugging, I always set it up by default without even thinking about it. So even when creating my test projects to try and pinpoint the bug, I set it up without even putting any thought into it. Well, it turns out that the library works by pulling some runtime trickery, so it can properly track objects. Things seem to work correctly now that I've disabled it, so I believe that it was the source of my problems.

Now I feel bad about jumping to conclusions about it being a bug, but at the time I couldn't see anything in my own code that could possibly cause that problem.